# How to retrieve and modify element from priority queue

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I am trying to call the following:

```
Event& event = events.top();  //This line throws an error because event isn't const
events.pop();
event.process();  //But event can't be const because this function is intentionally not const
```

Where `events` is a priority queue, and `process` will modify the object.  However, `events.top()` returns a `const &`.  I believe that the copy constructor doesn't exist because `Event` is a abstract class, containing pure virtual functions.

Hence, I only see two options here:

1. Remove the pure virtual functions
2. Use some magic casting to remove the `const`.

I don't really like either of those options.  **Is there a better way to pop, and then modify, the top abstract element from this priority queue?**

As a side note, `process()` doesn't change anything contained in the base Event class, only its subclasses need that functionality.

Comment: If you take a reference to an item in a container, and then remove the item from the container, you are left with a dangling reference.

Comment: Doesn't pop return the top element?

Comment: @EdHeal in [`std::priority_queue<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop), no. it simply removes the element (and heap-downs as needed to position the next winner).

Comment: You haven't explained what you're trying to do. How do you want to "modify" the `Event`? And why?

Comment: @WhozCraig - That is an assumption that it is implemented as such

Comment: @EdHeal which part, that it `std:priority_queue<> is implemented as a heap, or that `pop()` returns `void` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I need the reference because `Event` is abstract.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure why that is relevant.  It seems feasible that I should be able to call a non-const function on an object from a PriorityQueue, even if the object is abstract.

Comment: If calling a non-const function were allowed, it would mean changing the state of the object thereby changing the underlying heap structure [breaking the the top()'s time gurantee's of O(1)]

Comment: I'm surprised you can have abstract objects in a priority queue anyway. Normally the standard containers don't work that well with inheritance - it's normally better to use a `unique_ptr` to wrap the object in.

Comment: @NathanMerrill That design is intentional. Wth the item still in position at the head of the queue, what do you think happens when your non-const modification to said-item in fact *changes* its priority so it has no earthly business being at the head of the queue any longer? That modification was under no watchful eye of the queue's item management, Now, push another item on the queue. How does the queue know the item still residing at the head position shouldn't be there, and thus comparison against it as the current "winner" is futile? In short there is no better way. top, pop, mod, push.

Comment: @NathanMerrill: No it doesn't seem feasible, any more than it does to be able to mutate a key in a `std::set` or a `std::map`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That was the trick.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.